# Should I use Terraform registry modules or use Terraform resources?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to understand when is it better to use the Terraform registry modules instead of using the "classic" resource definition and build your own custom modules.

For example, on an AWS environment, a VPC could be defined using registry modules

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
......
```

or via resource

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

I understand that the `module vpc` make use of the resource `aws_vpc` along with a lot of other resources.

I'm also trying to make a cons/pro list so I could better understand future implications and do the right decision when starting a new Iac project.

Comment: I was just interested on best practices . In the end i decided to create my own modules and go with something similar from this :https://medium.com/@geraldhaxhi/how-to-structure-your-terraform-code-1caea8235e57

Answer (score 1):

Its up to you. The `terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws` allows you to create vpc easily if you want standard setup. The moment you want to make something non-standard, you will find that using the module is not possible without forking it out and modifying.

So if you want to have **full control** over all aspects of your VPC, its better to create your own module rather then using existing one.